How can I disable logging for the Spring Boot test ApplicationContextRunner (logging.level.root=warn isn't working)
I'm creating a Spring Boot starter and I'm using ApplicationContextRunner in my tests, but passing in logging.level.root=warn as a property value isn't working for me.
With a test like the following I still see debug logs, and there are even more of them once I actually add my .withConfiguration(...:
@Test
void someTest() {
    new ApplicationContextRunner()
            .withPropertyValues("logging.level.root=warn")
            .run(context -> {
                assertNull(context.getStartupFailure());
            });
}

16:04:34.115 [Test worker] DEBUG org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext - Refreshing org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@46271dd6
16:04:34.128 [Test worker] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.context.annotation.internalConfigurationAnnotationProcessor'
16:04:34.146 [Test worker] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.context.event.internalEventListenerProcessor'
16:04:34.148 [Test worker] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.context.event.internalEventListenerFactory'
16:04:34.149 [Test worker] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.context.annotation.internalAutowiredAnnotationProcessor'
16:04:34.151 [Test worker] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.context.annotation.internalCommonAnnotationProcessor'
16:04:34.204 [Test worker] DEBUG org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext - Closing org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@46271dd6, started on Wed Apr 10 16:04:34 EDT 2024ctory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Creating shared instance of singleton bean

I am using Spring Boot 2.7.18, running the tests with Gradle 8.7, and I don't have any logback xml files currently.

Hmm, that's interesting. Could you try changing it to capital-case WARN or OFF and see if that does anything?
@Test
void someTest() {
    new ApplicationContextRunner()
            .withPropertyValues("logging.level.root=WARN")
            .run(context -> {
                assertNull(context.getStartupFailure());
            });
}

@Test
void someTest() {
    new ApplicationContextRunner()
            .withPropertyValues("logging.level.root=OFF")
            .run(context -> {
                assertNull(context.getStartupFailure());
            });
}

If that still doesn't work, maybe you can try creating a folder called "resources" under the "test" folder and add the logback-test.xml file there
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <include resource="org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/base.xml" />
    <logger name="org.springframework" level="OFF"/>
</configuration>

